# Excel "IF" formula error

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I would like to create a formula in my MS-Excel Sheet. The Logic is given below:

The value of "A10" (cell) will be.....

- equal to "A4", if A4>=A9 or
- equal to "A5", if A6>=A9 & A9>A4 or
- equal to A6, if A6>=A9 & A9>A5 & A4 or
- Return "Empty" if A9>A6/A5/A4

(Here the value in order of "A6>A5>A4" and "A9" is the value with which all the other value are to be compared.)

I tried "IF" formula but it failed.

Comment: What exact formula did you try?

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF (A4>=A9; A4; IF (AND (A6>=A9; A9>A4); A5; IF (AND(A6>=A9; A9>A5; A9>A4); A6; IF ((AND (A9>A6; A9>A5; A9>A4); "Empty"; "This couldn't be possible"))))
```

Comment: Thanks David, for your kind help. I'm truly thankful to "wbogacz", too. I just edited your's Formula a little & got what I desire. But all credits goes to you...friend. Pl see what I did...

Comment: Thanks David, for your kind help. I'm truly thankful to "wbogacz", too. I just edited yours Formula a little & got what I desire. But all credits goes to you... DEar friend. Pl see what I did....>>> "=IF(A4>=A9,A4,IF(AND(**A5**(in place of A6)>=A9,A9>A4),A5,IF(AND(A6>=A9,A9>A5,A9>A4),A6,IF(AND(A9>A6,A9>A5,A9>A4),**""**(in place of EMPTY)))))".  Thanks again.

Comment: THE EDITED FORMULA >>>> =IF(A4>=A9,A4,IF(AND(A5>=A9,A9>A4),A5,IF(AND(A6>=A9,A9>A5,A9>A4),A6,IF(AND(A9>A6,A9>A5,A9>A4),""))))

Answer (score 2):

With all the help from @David and @wbogacz, and a tiny bit of editing from my end, the desired formula is stated below:

```
=IF(A4>=A9,A4,IF(AND(A5>=A9,A9>A4),A5,IF(AND(A6>=A9,A9>A5,A9>A4),A6,IF(AND(A9>A6,A9>A5,A9>A4),""))))
```

Comment: In the future, please do not sign your posts and remove all the excess that is not directly related to the question. See [FAQ#signatures]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(A4>=A9,A4,IF(AND(A6>=A9,A9>A4),A5,IF(AND(A6>=A9,A9>A5,A9>A4),A6,IF(AND(A9>A6,A9>A5,A9>A4),"Empty"))))
```

But generally I would put empty quotes where the string "Empty" exists.

tested with values:

```
a4=444,a5=555,a6=666
```

Result:

```
Test1 a9=1000,a10="Empty"
Test2 a9=400,a10=444
Test3 a9=500,a10=555
Test4 a9=600,a10=555
```

UPDATE: to get A6 as the answer would not be possible given the conditions as stated, since A5 precedes it in the formula. However, if the condition for A5 also ANDed A9<A5, this could yield 666 for a10 in Test4.

Comment: Thanks WBOGACZ, for your kind help. I'm truly thankful to David, too. I just edited yours Formula a little & got what I desire. But all credits goes to you... DEar friend. Pl see what I did....>>> "=IF(A4>=A9,A4,IF(AND(**A5**(in place of A6)>=A9,A9>A4),A5,IF(AND(A6>=A9,A9>A5,A9>A4),A6,IF(AND(A9>A6,A9>A5,A9>A4),**""**(in place of EMPTY)))))".  Thanks again.

Comment: THE EDITED FORMULA >>>> =IF(A4>=A9,A4,IF(AND(A5>=A9,A9>A4),A5,IF(AND(A6>=A9,A9>A5,A9>A4),A6,IF(AND(A9>A6,A9>A5,A9>A4),""))))